# small javascript solution need : is this line a valid code?

Tags: javascript

**In Html file,I have many statements like this :**

```
<li class="menu"><a href="#">1st menu</a></li>
```

**And in javascript file,I have code like this :**

```
1. function onload()
2. {
3.  var lists=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
4.  for(var i=0;i<lists.length;i++){
5.      if(lists[i].className=="menu"){
6.          lists[i].a.onclick=genmenu;
7.      }
8.  }
9. }

function genmenu(){
    alert("this is an alert");
    return false;
}
```

**Problem  is, if i click on the link '1st menu', it doesn't show alert. But if i change the line 6 and write:**

```
lists[i].onclick=genmenu;
```

**Then this link works and show alert.**

**My Question, Why line 6**  (lists[i].a.onclick=genmenu;)  **does'nt work? Isn't it a valid code?**

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access nested elements as members of another element:

```
lists[i].a
```

This is looking for a member of the `list[i]` element with a name of `a` - it's not looking for an anchor within it. If you wanted the anchor, you'd write:

```
list[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is not a property of `li`, it is a nested tag.  You'd have to use

```
lists[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

As a side note, be careful with `if(lists[i].className=="menu")` because if one of your li's class is "menu otherClass" it will no longer work.  jQuery has a good method to handle this:  hasClass() but it'd be easy to write something similar if you're not using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you too for Quick feedback

Comment: In fact, there's already something rather similar to jQuery's selection stuff...`document.querySelectorAll('li.menu a[href]')` will give you all the links inside a list item with a class of 'menu'.  Difference being, (1) jQuery works in IE7 :P, and (2) jQuery adds pseudo-selectors and such that aren't present in some versions of CSS.

Comment: querySelectorAll is part of the DOM standard and available on most modern browsers without the need to load JQuery. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers your code can be simpler and more efficient:

```
function onload () {
   var links = document.querySelectorAll ('li.menu a[href]');
   for (var i= links.length; i--;) {
     links[i].addEventListener ('click', genmenu, false);
   }
}

function genmenu () {
    alert ("this is an alert");
    return false;
}
```

For more information, see [the documentation on `querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll).